# How to write the < > simbols spanish latine keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

Have a laptop with a spanish latine keyboard with ubuntu 20.04, the problem is than the "< >"  simbols have a very own dedicate key for both of them, key who does nothing on Linux.

It is there a way like on windows using key combination alt-62 or a way to force the key to work?

**-SOLVED-**

There is a key combination, for spanish keyboards Ralt+Shift+z, Ralt+Shift+x.

Comment: Hello. This is very confusing . Please read and correct. Also what version of Ubuntu and what keyboard language?

Comment: In Windows "Alt"+"6"+"2" will produce `>`. The equivalent in GNOME is "Ctrl"+"Shift"+"U"+"3"+"E"+"Enter". Similarly, for `<` use "Ctrl"+"Shift"+"U"+"3"+"C"+"Enter".

Comment: @David I agree the question is not very well written but the meaning is clear enough. However it would be helpful to understand what language the questioner wants to use and to confirm that the keyboard is configured accordingly. That way the relatively torturous workaround suggested by FedKad would not be needed

Comment: @PonJar Good for you I can not make any sense of it. Yes I already asked about the keyboard. No answer from the OP yet.

Comment: Judging by this questioner’s profile I am guessing this answer may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/259879/how-can-i-get-the-correct-spanish-keyboard-layout#259888

Comment: FedKad it works for my at some emergency but cannot use it for coding, too hard.

Comment: The key should work as long as you have the correct keyboard layout set. Do you?

Comment: PonJar forgot  to tell, need a non graphical solution, half of my doing  is under non graphical terminal.

ChanganAuto unless there is another Spanish language non Latin Spanish or Spain Spanish, i think i have the correct one, also the laptop assembler is a very unknown enterprise, the key  < > are in the opposite side of standard location, think than the problem may come from there.

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it 24 hours later. That way anyone searching for an answer to the same issue has a better chance if finding it

Comment: PonJar i am just not very familiarized with some of the site´s features, thanks

Comment: possible answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074231/one-key-has-wrong-keyboard-layout

Answer (score 1):

There is a key combination, for spanish keyboards Ralt+Shift+z, Ralt+Shift+x.